# Finding sum of fibonacci numbers recursively

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I'm a bit stuck here. I know a particular fibonacci number can be found recursively as so:

```
int fib (int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;

    else 
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

And I know iteratively I could call that function n times to find the sum of fibonacci numbers

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    sum += fib(i);
}
```

But I'm having a hard time coming up with a recursive function to find the sum. I don't think it would be much different than the original fibonacci function. (This is for an assignment aimed at improving my ability to write ocaml syntax, not writing recursive functions)

Comment: Did you try to google it ?

Comment: Yes, quite a bit actually.

Comment: weird indeed considering that google returns  321,000 results for "fibonacci recursion"

Comment: fib(0) should be 0, not 1.

Comment: that's right, thank you. I've changed it to return n in the case that n <= 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since no one else is bothering to answer your question, here you go:

```
int fib_sum(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return fib_sum(n-1) + fib_sum(n-2) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want a recursive solution involving only fib_sum(), here is one:

```
int fib_sum (int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    if (n == 1)
        return 2;
    return fib_sum(n-1) + fib_sum(n - 2) + 1;
}
```

Comment: But surely `fib_sum(0)` should be `0` and `fib_sum(1)` should be `1`.

Comment: That would be unusual: [Fibonacci Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number)

Answer (score 3):

Observing that fib_sum(n) == fib(n+2) - 1 you can use more or less the same function.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will work fine

```html
int fib_sum (int n){
  if(n<=1) {
    return n;
  }
  else {
    return fib_Sum(n-1) + fib_Sum(n-2) + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that counting of elements starts from 0
so elements   0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13
then position 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
So if n = 5, the sum = (0+1+1+2+3+5)=12

recursive function will be:
 `int fib_sum (int n){ if(n<=1) { return n; } else { return fib_Sum(n-1) + fib_Sum(n-2) + 1; } }`